# how do i fix leaks created by man 2 stat members in c

Tags: c, macos, unix, malloc, free

i am re-implimenting the unix ls command, but when i test for leaks it says:Process 44151: 248 nodes malloced for 45 KB, Process 44151: 28 leaks for 560 total leaked bytes. so i tried to free the pwd, and grp. but it says the i am freeing memory that was never allocated.

```
static int      one(const struct dirent *unused)
{
    (void)unused;
    return (1);
}

void            ls_l(void)
{
    struct stat     statbuf;
    struct group    *grp;
    struct passwd   *pwd;
    struct dirent   **sd;
    int             n;
    int             i;

    pwd = getpwuid((geteuid()));
    n = scandir(".", &sd, one, alphasort);
    i = 1;
    while (i < n)
    {
        while (strncmp(sd[i]->d_name, ".", 1) == 0)
            i++;
        if (stat(sd[i]->d_name, &statbuf) == 0)
        {
            ft_perm(sd[i]->d_name);
            ft_printf(" %-2d %4s  ", statbuf.st_nlink, pwd->pw_name);
            if ((grp = getgrgid(statbuf.st_gid)) != NULL)
                ft_printf(" %-8.8s %5d %s %s\n",grp->gr_name,
                        (int)statbuf.st_size,ft_group(ctime(&statbuf.st_mtime)),
                        sd[i]->d_name);
            else
                ft_printf(" %-8d %5d %s %s\n", statbuf.st_gid,
                        (int)statbuf.st_size,ft_group(ctime(&statbuf.st_mtime)),
                        sd[i]->d_name);
        }
        free(sd[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(sd);
}
```

Comment: There are no leaks created by `stat`. Why do you think there are? did you use *valgrind*?

Comment: i put the program to sleep, and i used the ps command on my mac, then used leaks to find leaks

Comment: man getpwuid:  'The return value may point to a static area'

Comment: @johnsondubula details like this should be in the question itself.

Comment: If you want recursive, thread-safe operation, there is getpwuid_r()

Answer (score 0):

```
while (strncmp(sd[i]->d_name, ".", 1) == 0)
            i++;
// code
free(sd[i]);
```

There's the cause of your memory leak. You're never freeing the elements of sd whose filenames start with a period.

Also, I'd use `sd[i]->d_name[0] == '.'` for that comparison. `strncmp()` is overkill for this. A fixed version of your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
   while (i < n && sd[i]->d_name[0] == '.') {
       free(sd[i++]);
   }
   if (i == n) {
      break;
   }

    // code

    free(sd[i]);
}
free(sd);
```

In addition, this handles cases where *every* file returned is a dotfile, where your original one would result in reading past the end of the `sd` array in that situation.

Comment: `sd[i]->d_name[0] == '.'`might be *underkill* `.bashrc`starts with a period, for instance. BTW: `strncmp(sd[i]->d_name, ".", 1)` has the same problem,

Comment: @wildplasser OP said he's writing a version of ls, which filters out dotfiles by default. (Adding support for the `-a` option requires some trivial changes to avoid that check that aren't worth including here, especially when the main point is fixing the memory leak.)

Comment: thank you guys, its resolved, the dot files where not freed